# Integration as limit of sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I have facing trouble regarding the following 2 problems.Please Help.

Evaluate:

1. $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left[\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})+\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})+...+\sin(\frac{n\pi}{n}) \right]$
2. $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left[(1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2})^2...(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2})^n \right]^{\frac1n}$

I know that $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{r=1}^n f(\frac rn)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$

But I can not put the above two in this form.

For 1. it is $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n \sin(\frac {r\pi}n)$

and for 2. I have found
$e^{\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{r=1}^{n} r\ln(1+\frac{r^2}{n^2})}$

But I cannot proceed further.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first limit diverges to $+\infty$, unless you have a typo.

Comment: So does the second limit.

Comment: I have checked.I have written exactly same as in the source.But there may be a typo.Can you please tell me why are these diverging?thnx again

Comment: The sum in the first limit has a simple closed form: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\frac{k\pi}{n}}=\cot{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$. Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cot{\frac{\pi}{2n}}=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you.I didn't know that.Please tell me how to show this or please suggest from where I can know these forms.

Comment: The term $\sin{\frac{k\pi}{n}}$ can be written as the imaginary part of the complex exponential 
$e^{\frac{ik\pi}{n}}=(e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}})^k$. Summing over $k$ is then easily seen to be a finite geometric series, which has a very familiar closed form expression for the $n$-th partial sum. Finally, find the imaginary part of the expression for the complex sum to get the expression for the sum of sines. The algebra is tedious but straightforward, assuming you're familiar with basic complex number algebra.

Comment: Thank you very much.Let me try.Hope I can do this because I know basics of complex algebra.

Comment: For the second problem, consider the sum you derived from it.  If $r > n/2$, then $r \ln \left(1+\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right) > \frac{n}{2} \ln \frac{5}{4}$. But there are $n/2$ of those terms, so the sum is greater than $\frac{n^2}{4} \ln \frac{5}{4}$.  Even after the multiplication by the $\frac{1}{n}$ on the left of the summation sign, you are left with a diverging quantity.